# Elasticsearch cannot start when bind to public ip address

Tags: elasticsearch

if i leave the `network.host` commented out in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`, it will start like normal (`curl localhost:9200` returns result as expected).

However, if I set `network.host = <public-ip>` then `sudo service elasticsearch restart` it will says OK but then the status of elasticsearch is `not running`.

what did I do wrong in this case?

System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Update: Fixed by binding it to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Fixed by binding it to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to fix this is to pass the `bootstrap` tests in `elasticsearch`:

add to `/etc/security/limits.conf` something like:

```
# elasticsearch
*               hard    nofile          65536
*               hard    nproc           2048
```

> Be careful with the network configuration!
>   Never expose an unprotected node to the public internet. ([elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html))

A secure solution would be to bind to a `loopback` interface & create an [`ssh` tunnel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) from the host that needs access `=> elasticsearch`