# Cannot bind Public Elastic IP to Elastic Search on EC2 running Windows Server 2016

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I want to run Elastic Search on an EC2 Instance, and access it globally.
But upon changing its config to

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
network.host: XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

(Associated Elastic IP)

It throws an error :

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

I suppose it was unable to bind to the public Ip Address

**Then**
I tried binding it to `0.0.0.0` as mentioned in [Elasticsearch cannot start when bind to public ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770851/elasticsearch-cannot-start-when-bind-to-public-ip-address)
(I had to add `discovery.seed_hosts: []` since I am running a single instance).
It runs, but locally.

I cannot find any way to access it globally. 
Help!

Also I have added port 9200 in inbound rules or EC2

PS: Please mention any additional required information in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **had to add an inbound rule in windows firewall** for port range **9200-9300**

**Steps** :

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Open Windows Firewall
3. In the left panel -> Advance Settings
4. In the Inbound rules, see on the right panel there should be an option of `New Rule`
5. Click on Port then Next
6. Select TCP Port
7. In Specific Port option add range `9200-9300`
8. Next-> Allow Connection (You may have to select `Allow if secured` according to requirement).
9. Next -> Next -> Give It a name -> Finish

Hope this helps anyone facing the similar problem.